# Javascript get textbox value within the same function

Tags: javascript

When i use a single function created multiple html table row by using for loop, i created a textbox and a button in every row as well.

What i failed to do is when user click on the button, it will get the textbox value (within the same row). I got the error :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Please check on below bidbtn.onclick = function() part:

```
function tablelisting(){
    for(i=0;i<domainarray.length;i++){
        var newtr = document.createElement("tr")
        var newtd1 = document.createElement("td")
        var newtd2 = document.createElement("td")
        var newtd3 = document.createElement("td")
        var newtd4 = document.createElement("td")
        var newtd5 = document.createElement("td")
        var bidbtn = document.createElement("button")
        var textbox = document.createElement("input")

        bidbtn.innerHTML = "Bid"
        bidbtn.setAttribute("class","btn1")
        //bidbtn.setAttribute("onclick","bid()")

        textbox.setAttribute("type","text")
        textbox.setAttribute("placeholder","USD")
        textbox.setAttribute("class","bidtextbox")
        textbox.setAttribute("id","bidinput"+i)

        newtr.appendChild(newtd1)
        newtd1.innerHTML = domainarray[i].domain
        newtr.appendChild(newtd2)
        newtd2.innerHTML = domainarray[i].dtcreate
        newtr.appendChild(newtd3)
        newtd3.innerHTML = domainarray[i].dtexpire
        newtr.appendChild(newtd4)
        newtd4.innerHTML = (Date.parse(domainarray[i].dtexpire) - Date.parse(formatDate(new Date())))/86400000 + " days"
        newtr.appendChild(newtd5)
        newtd5.appendChild(textbox)
        newtd5.appendChild(bidbtn)

        bidbtn.onclick = function(){
            var bidamount = document.getElementById("bidinput"+i).value
            console.log(bidamount)
        }

        domtable.appendChild(newtr)
    }
}
```

I know every bidbtn is tie with the textbox within the same row, but i don't know how to get the vale of textbox after user fill in the amount and click the bidbtn.

How to make the bidamount = the value of textbox after user fill in the amount?

Comment: plz make a code snippet. It will help a lot

Comment: What is `domainarray` and `domtable`. You are using them in your script, yet they are not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `i` like that, because it is changed every iteration of the loop. When the click handler fires, it will always be the value of the last iteration, so the click handler won't work as expected. To work around this, use:

```
domarray.forEach(function (elm, index) {
  // ...
});
```

You can read more about `Array.prototype.forEach()` in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Now, just in case you realize `domarray` is not a real array but something like a nodelist, here's how to do `forEach()` in that case.

```
[].forEach.call(domarray, function (elm, index) {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: Get button parent -> table cell, get row, find element with .bidtextbox class, get value

```
bidbtn.onclick = function(){
    var bidamount = this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".bidtextbox").value;
    console.log(bidamount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

1) Create a onclick="bid(Pass the row number here)", and set an id for every row of button.

```
function tablelisting(){
    for(i=0;i<domainarray.length;i++){
        var newtr = document.createElement("tr")
        var newtd1 = document.createElement("td")
        var newtd5 = document.createElement("td")

        var bidbtn = document.createElement("button")
        var textbox = document.createElement("input")

        bidbtn.innerHTML = "Bid"
        bidbtn.setAttribute("class","btn1")
        bidbtn.setAttribute("onclick","bid("+i+")")
        bidbtn.setAttribute("id","btn"+i)


        newtr.appendChild(newtd1)
        newtd1.innerHTML = domainarray[i].domain

        newtr.appendChild(newtd5)
        newtd5.appendChild(textbox)
        newtd5.appendChild(bidbtn)



        domtable.appendChild(newtr)
    }
}
```

2) Create a bid function to get the row number, then get the parent's child element value:

```
function bid (b){
    var bidamount = document.getElementById("btn"+b).parentElement.firstChild.value;

}
```